# Can the below query be optimized

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query below:

```
DECLARE @Power VARCHAR(10), @Button VARCHAR(10), @Casing VARCHAR(10), @Screen VARCHAR(10)
SELECT @Power = ActivityId FROM t_Activity WHERE ActivityName = 'PhonePowersUp?'
SELECT @Button = ActivityId FROM t_Activity WHERE ActivityName = 'T/S and Buttons functioning OK?'
SELECT @Casing = ActivityId FROM t_Activity WHERE ActivityName = 'Casing - no major defects?'
SELECT @Screen = ActivityId FROM t_Activity WHERE ActivityName = 'LCD works OK?'

SELECT
    HQ.HandsetQuoteId [HandsetQuoteId], SS.Name [quote_status], HQ.QuoteDate [Quote Date], INS.DateInspected [DateInspected], PA.IMEI [IMEI_Quoted],
    PA1.IMEI [IMEI_Inspected],  INS.Grade [Grade], PB.PackageBoxName [PackageBoxName], CC.Name [ContactChannel], PhnBrd.Name [Brand], PM.ModelName [ModelQuoted],
    PM1.ModelName [ModelInspected], U.FirstName [FirstName], U.Surname [Surname], U.Username [Username], UW.WarehouseId [WarehouseId], W.Name [Warehouse Name],
    HQA.Value [Original Quote Value], HQ.QuoteValue [Quote Value], INS.InspectionValue [InspectionValue], HQ.AgreedValue [Agreed Value], CUS.FirstName [Store Name],
    DATEDIFF(DAY, HQ.QuoteDate, GETDATE()) [Quote Age],
    [ST_POWER] = CASE WHEN (CHARINDEX(','+ @Power +',', ','+PAR.Ok+',') > 0) THEN 'YES' WHEN (CHARINDEX(','+ @Power +',', ','+PAR.Fault+',') > 0) THEN 'NO' ELSE NULL END,
    [ST_BUTTONS] = CASE WHEN (CHARINDEX(','+ @Button +',', ','+PAR.Ok+',') > 0) THEN 'YES' WHEN (CHARINDEX(','+ @Button +',', ','+PAR.Fault+',') > 0) THEN 'NO' ELSE NULL END,
    [ST_CASING] = CASE WHEN (CHARINDEX(','+ @Casing +',', ','+PAR.Ok+',') > 0) THEN 'YES' WHEN (CHARINDEX(','+ @Casing +',', ','+PAR.Fault+',') > 0) THEN 'NO' ELSE NULL END,
    [ST_Screen] = CASE WHEN (CHARINDEX(','+ @Screen +',', ','+PAR.Ok+',') > 0) THEN 'YES' WHEN (CHARINDEX(','+ @Screen +',', ','+PAR.Fault+',') > 0) THEN 'NO' ELSE NULL END,
    st_deduct = PAR.PercentageDeduction, wt_deduct = MAX(APD1.PercentageDeduction)
FROM t_Inspection AS INS
INNER JOIN t_HandsetQuote                   HQ      ON HQ.HandsetQuoteId = INS.HandsetQuoteId
INNER JOIN t_QuoteHeader                    QH      ON QH.QuoteHeaderId = HQ.QuoteHeaderId
INNER JOIN t_Customer                       CUS     ON CUS.CustomerId = QH.CustomerId
INNER JOIN t_ContactChannel                 CC      ON CC.ContactChannelId = CUS.ContactChannelId
INNER JOIN t_PackageBoxHandset              PBH     ON PBH.HandsetQuoteId = HQ.HandsetQuoteId
INNER JOIN t_PackageBox                     PB      ON PB.PackageBoxId = PBH.PackageBoxId
INNER JOIN t_PackageBoxStatus               PBS     ON PBS.PackageBoxStatusId = PB.PackageBoxStatusId
INNER JOIN t_StockStatus                    SS      ON SS.StockStatusId = HQ.StockStatusId
INNER JOIN t_QuoteStatus                    QS      ON QS.QuoteStatusId = QH.QuoteStatusId
INNER JOIN t_PhoneAudit                     PA      ON PA.PhoneAuditId = HQ.QuotePhoneAuditId
INNER JOIN t_PhoneModel                     PM      ON PM.PhoneModelId = PA.PhoneModelId AND PA.PhoneAuditId = HQ.QuotePhoneAuditId
INNER JOIN t_PhoneBrand                     PhnBrd  ON PM.PhoneBrandId = PhnBrd.PhoneBrandId
INNER JOIN t_PhoneAudit                     PA1     ON PA1.PhoneAuditId = HQ.InspectionPhoneAuditId
INNER JOIN t_PhoneModel                     PM1     ON PM1.PhoneModelId = PA1.PhoneModelId AND PA1.PhoneAuditId = HQ.InspectionPhoneAuditId
INNER JOIN t_PhoneBrand                     PhnBrd1 ON PM1.PhoneBrandId = PhnBrd1.PhoneBrandId
INNER JOIN t_User                           U       ON INS.InspectorId = U.UserId
INNER JOIN t_UserWarehouse                  UW      ON U.UserId = UW.UserId
INNER JOIN t_Warehouse                      W       ON UW.WarehouseId = W.WarehouseId
LEFT JOIN t_HandsetQuoteAdditionalInfo      HQA     ON HQ.HandsetQuoteId = HQA.HandsetQuoteId AND HQA.KeyName LIKE '%OriginalQuoteValue%'
LEFT JOIN t_PhoneAuditRetail                PAR     ON PAR.HandsetQuoteId = HQ.HandsetQuoteId
LEFT JOIN t_Activity_PercentageDeduction    APD     ON APD.ActivityPercentageDeductionId = PAR.DeductionTypeId
LEFT JOIN t_HandsetQuoteActivity            HQA1    ON HQA1.HandsetQuoteId = HQ.HandsetQuoteId AND HQA1.activitystarttime = (
                                        CASE
                                            WHEN ((SELECT Count(1) FROM t_HandsetQuoteActivity WHERE  HandsetQuoteId = HQA1.HandsetQuoteId AND ActivityStartTime <= QH.Cache_QuoteAcceptedDate AND ActivityId = HQA1.ActivityId) > 0)
                                            THEN (SELECT Max(ActivityStartTime) FROM t_HandsetQuoteActivity WHERE HandsetQuoteId = HQA1.HandsetQuoteId AND ActivityStartTime <= QH.Cache_QuoteAcceptedDate AND ActivityId = HQA1.ActivityId GROUP BY HandsetQuoteId, ActivityId)
                                        ELSE
                                            (SELECT Min(ActivityStartTime) FROM t_HandsetQuoteActivity WHERE HandsetQuoteId = HQA1.HandsetQuoteId AND ActivityStartTime >= QH.Cache_QuoteAcceptedDate AND ActivityId = HQA1.ActivityId GROUP BY HandsetQuoteId, ActivityId)
                                        END)
LEFT JOIN t_Activity_PercentageDeduction    APD1    ON APD1.ActivityId = HQA1.ActivityId
LEFT JOIN t_PhoneAuditRetail                PAR1    ON PAR1.HandsetQuoteId = HQA1.HandsetQuoteId AND PAR1.HandsetQuoteId = HQ.HandsetQuoteId
WHERE Ins.DateInspected > GETDATE()-90
GROUP BY HQ.HandsetQuoteId, SS.Name, QH.CreatedDate, INS.DateInspected, PA.IMEI, PA1.IMEI, INS.Grade, PB.PackageBoxName, CC.Name, PhnBrd.Name, PM.ModelName, PM1.ModelName,
U.FirstName, U.Surname, U.Username, UW.WarehouseId, W.Name, HQA.Value, HQ.QuoteValue, INS.InspectionValue, HQ.AgreedValue, CUS.Firstname, HQ.QuoteDate, PAR.Ok, PAR.Fault,
PAR.PercentageDeduction
```

This is a `Select` query and it only select records nothing much, but this query is selecting more than 1 million records, so it takes more than 30 mins to show the data.

I need your help to know how it can be optimized.

Attached is the screenshot of the table design which has maximum data:

[image]
[image]

Comment: You should post the table definitions, including indexes, too.

Comment: Can you tell us what you have tried so far to optimize it. You should first try to do it yourself and then you should ask a question if you are stuck somewhere doing that :-)

Comment: @Pankaj i want to replace `Case` statement, because they are really slowing the query execution

Answer (score 0):

I'd just go with an indexed view. An indexed view is like storing the result of the query on the hard drive, and letting SQL Server keep it up to date automatically. Then you can just run much simpler queries on this indexed view and save a potentially huge amount of time. Just watch out for storage space, as it is a physical copy of some of the data from the underlying database! (How much depends on how exclusive the SELECT query it is based on is)

```
-- Create a view from the query
CREATE VIEW dbo.HandsetView
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
--**** Original query goes here
GO
```

Where it says "original query goes here," that's where you can just put your current query. The only thing is, I'd either figure out a way to change your query so you don't have to declare variables like that, or you will have to leave the parts that filter by them out of the indexed view. Of course, you can use these later to query the indexed view, but it won't be quite as performant as it could be. You also should leave out the `GETDATE()` predicate in the `WHERE` clause and save that for when you query the view.

```
-- Index the view
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_cl_handset_view
ON dbo.HandsetView(DateInspected);
GO
```

This allows you to just query the view, which is stored physically on disk, and therefore is precomputed:

```
-- Re-run query, this time using the indexed view.
SELECT   *
FROM     dbo.HandsetView WITH (NOEXPAND)
WHERE    HandsetView.DateInspected > GETDATE() - 90;
```

Above is how you would query the indexed view once it's made. You can query it just like it's a normal table, except make sure you have the `WITH (NOEXPAND)` option on if you're not using SQL Server Enterprise, as the SQL optimizer will otherwise query the underlying tables and thus negate any performance advantages to this.

Indexed views can be a little a finicky, so make sure you jump through the hoops described [on this MSDN article about indexed views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432(v=sql.110).aspx#Restrictions).